# How to bypass all proxy settings for choco

Tags: windows, proxy, chocolatey, choco

On Windows I've got a proxy set a computer level (netsh winhttp show proxy) and user network level settings > network > proxy.

The proxy is denying almost everything. It is being picked by choco when running:

```
choco install javaruntime

Chocolatey v0.10.15
Installing the following packages:
javaruntime
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
javaruntime not installed. An error occurred during installation:
 The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. Forbidden
```

I know the instance has internet access without the proxy. I have admin access on this machine.
I would like to not use the proxy at all when choco is running.

I tried using the proxy bypass option:

```
--proxy-bypass-list=VALUE
     ProxyBypassList - Comma separated list of regex locations to bypass on
       proxy. Requires explicity proxy (`--proxy` or config setting). Overrides
       the default proxy bypass list of ''.*''. Available in 0.10.4+.

choco install javaruntime --proxy='' --proxy-bypass-list="'.*'" -y
```

But I get the same 403. Is that list of regex using another format?

I've looked at the documentation but couldn't find anything more: https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/guides/usage/proxy-settings-for-chocolatey